# Choose and duplicate a row from table1 to table2 within a form without typing it manually

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with several tables, two of these tables contain similar columns.
I want to add data from one table row to another.

Seems like there is no **doubleClick** event in vba for tables.
Otherwise that should've been an optimal way to select a row and add it to the other table.

Is there a way to add a row from one of the tables to the other without typing it?

I have considered adding a command button and then first select the row and afterwards click on the button (or functional event)

Comment: Can copy/paste. Can run code to simply populate a field by referencing another field. Why are you duplicating data between tables? Why does form have several tables in RecordSource?

Comment: A query can easily do this but without data showing what you have and what you want I can't help you write the query.

Comment: The tablels are subforms in the form, what I'm looking for is to solve this with help of vba and possibly events  in the form.

Comment: Still not clear what you want. Still don't know why you are duplicating data. You have subform container SourceObject set to a table? Build a form to use as SourceObject and put code behind that form.

Comment: Im duplicating data from a table that show storage data to a table that is used for user input to change the storage data. Im keeping it in two seperate tables in the form because there are several users thats going to change storage data at the same time. The user input is transfered to a log and then sent to recalculate storage.